# How to charge a USB-C host with ACA alternative?

Tags: usb, wiring, cellphone, usb-host, usb-c

For old some micro usb devices, you can wire the ID pin so it is connected to the ground pin with a resistance of something like 36.5 kΩ. When the device is in host mode and connected to a device, this would allow the android host device to receive power from an external source when it was connected to the Vbus pin.

Basically, this allowed a device to be charged, while in host mode and still be in control of the peripheral device. I believe this kind of connection was known as accessory charging adaptors (ACA).

My question is, is there an alternative wiring to this for USB-C, can I buy some sort of adaptor, or even design some sort of board myself to go between a USB-C phone and a peripheral device?

Comment: Update, there is a board available from lavacomputers but generelly are only compatible with samsung tablets. They claim to be the only people on the market who do this. I don't really feel like pay 130 dollars for that adaptor plus shipping though, so a followup question I have is why aren't there more on the market?

Comment: https://lavasimulcharge.com/products/lavasync-usb-c-mobile-adapters/lavasync-usb-c-adapters-hubs/lavasync-1u-oem/

Comment: For future ref the micro ACA 36.5 kΩ behaviour is the RID_C case in https://composter.com.ua/documents/BC1.2_FINAL.pdf#page=63, but it isn't the part that allows the OTG device to be in control of a peripheral device (note how it sets up as the accessory as the A-dev and the OTG device as the B-dev). It would have to use Host Negotiation Protocol (HNP) or similar for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern USB environment a USB port carries two roles: data role, and power role. In USB Type-C framework the two roles are coupled/associated by default: host data role is associated with power supply role, and USB device is a power consumer.

Now, to make a host to act as consumer (to charge itself), the recent USB Type-C specification defines only one way to swap the power role while keeping the role as USB host. This way is to use a subset of power delivery specifications of so-called "Structured VDM" - Vendor Defined Messages. Typically the process is implemented by so-called "PD management IC" which provides PHY-level PD protocol communication over Type-C CC wire, all under control (typically over I2C) from an embedded controller. The overall protocol is quite complicated and is described in "USB Power Delivery Specifications" Rev3.0, which can be found in [USB-IF document library](https://www.usb.org/documents).